# How can we stop the execution of javascript for a while until a decision is made?

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I want to build my own popup box using div's (not the browser default). So when I display my own popup I want to stop the javascript execution until the user clicks a button on my own popup, same as the default confirmation popup in browsers. Is there a way to do this? If so how? I would like to avoid using jQuery.

Comment: Why not? quite easy. did you try ?

Comment: Not possible, use events and callback function.

Comment: It's relatively possible -I'm sure there's a solution on the net readily available

Comment: @JonathanBrooks "I want to stop the javascript execution until user clicks ..." Like I said, not possible in JavaScript.

Comment: i have googled but could not find solution in javascript. so many people are suggesting jquery but i want to know the solution in javascript. please point me to the solution (i mean please post the url) if it is available on net.

Comment: @Kyll Even an infinite loop wouldn't work, it would block the event firing too.

Comment: As noted you can't stop execution but process can be simply achieved using events with callbacks or promises

Answer (score 3):

You can't (and shouldn't) block JavaScript execution. It would be possible by introducing an endless while loop, but that would seriously degrade performance and also affect the handling of click events.

So, the best and probably only way to do this, is to use a callback that is called when you press a button. This does mean that you can't call this alternative confirm method in a synchronous way, though. Instead you can provide a callback that is executed when one of the buttons is pressed.

I hacked together an example. This is just made up on the fly, and only has some rudimentary styling. If it contains minor flaws, please forgive me.

```js
/**
 * The alternative confirmation function
 */
window.myConfirm = function(options) {
  // Create the elements
  var popup = document.createElement('div');
  var box = document.createElement('div');
  var ok = document.createElement('button');
  var cancel = document.createElement('button');
  
  // Style them
  popup.className = 'lightbox';
  box.className = 'dialog';
  ok.className = 'button buttonOK';
  cancel.className = 'button buttonCancel';
  
  // Button texts
  ok.innerText = 'OK';
  cancel.innerText = 'Cancel';
  
  // Click handlers.
  ok.onclick = function(event) {
    popup.parentNode.removeChild(popup);
    options.onConfirm();
  }
  cancel.onclick = function(event) {
    popup.parentNode.removeChild(popup);
    options.onDecline();
  };
  // Clicking the box does nothing.
  box.onclick = function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
  };
  // Clicking the popup equals cancel.
  popup.onclick = cancel.onclick;

  // Add all elements to the document.
  popup.appendChild(box);
  box.innerHTML = "<div><h2>" + options.title + "</h2>" + options.prompt + "</div>";
  
  box.appendChild(ok);
  box.appendChild(cancel);
  // Finally show the box.
  document.body.appendChild(popup);
};


/**
 * The call
 */
myConfirm({
  title: "Confirm",
  prompt: "Are you sure?",
  onConfirm: function() {
    // The code that is executed when user presses OK.
    alert('You confirmed');
  },
  onDecline: function() {
    // Code executed on cancel, or when clicking next to the box.
    alert('You declined');
  }
});
```

```css
.lightbox {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  text-align: center;
}

.dialog {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 50px;
}

.dialog div {
  text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of stopping the execution, get an input from the user and then continue from some point without using JavaScript popup boxes. You can build one on your own with html components and display it with buttons, provide call backs. You would need to block the window from user access, take the input and then unblock the window. You may use `Javascript` frameworks like `jQuery` to get a better styled, enhanced and optimized component. Here is piece of code demonstration:

### JavaScript

```
function myCancelClick() {
    hidePrompt();
    alert("Cancel");
}

function myOkClick(){
    hidePrompt();
    alert("Ok");
}

function showPrompt() {
    document.getElementById("promptPane").style.display = '';
    document.getElementById("displayPane").style.display = 'none';
}

function hidePrompt() {
    document.getElementById("promptPane").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("displayPane").style.display = '';
}
```

### HTML body

```
<body>
    <div id="displayPane">
        <input type="button" onclick="showPrompt()" value="Show Prompt"/>
    </div>
    <div id="promptPane" style="display: none;">
        <div id="myPrompt">what would you like to click?<input type="button" onclick='myCancelClick();' value="Cancel"/><input type="button" onclick='myOkClick();' value="Ok"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jithin4u/b0w4e4k7/)

Answer (score 0):

If you know, how much time you want to stop for; try using setTimeout() function of Javascript to produce a delay

Comment: OP needs a `sleep` method to emulate a modal window. `setTimeout` only delays the execution of its argument function, the code after a `setTimeout(...)` will be executed immediately.